# Is there any "intuitive" logical or double counting proof to this combinatorial identity

Tags: combinatorics

How can we prove this combinatorial identity

> $$\frac{{}^nC_r}{r+1}=\frac{{}^{n+1}C_{r+1}}{n+1}$$

How can we prove above combinatorial identity preferably by some intuitive logic or double counting approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a set with $n+1$ elements, count the pairs of one element and a subset of $r$ elements from the remaining.

First way: choose one element (first part of the pair), then choose $r$ among $n$ for the second part, that is $(n+1){n\choose r}$ possibilities.

Second way: choose $r+1$ elements, and pick one among them to get the first part of the pair and the remaining is the second part: $(r+1){n+1\choose r+1}$ possibilities.

Comment: Just realised this is same problem as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1289188), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/708485), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2446226) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/984998/) but in disguising different form!!! (Correct me if I am wrong.) To me [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2446226/combinatorial-intuition-of-identity#comment5053577_2446233) is most satisfying double counting proof.